# Explanation of a code

Tags: trigger, triggercontext

Can anyone explain the following code:

```
for(opportunity opp : trigger.new)
{
    opportunity oldOpp = trigger.oldMap.get(opp.id);
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't seem to do anything useful by itself. It's clearly part of an update trigger, and seems to be set up so that `opp` is the new value of a record and `oldOpp` is the old (pre-update) values for comparison.

Comment: @ca_peterson I know its not doing any useful... I was asking becoz I needed to understand the concept of this liner "opportunity oldOpp = trigger.oldMap.get(opp.id);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Trigger.new` contains opportunity records that have been inserted/updated/deleted, depending on which event triggered this.

It's looping through all those opportunities and for each one of them a new variable is created, in which the old state of the opportunity record is stored.

When I say old, I mean that this trigger is most likely running after insert/update or before/after delete. An opportunity record in your `trigger.new` set will have all the new field values that are about to be saved to database, whereas your oldOpp record will have the old values prior this trigger started executing.

Example: You have updated the opportunity stage from "Prospecting" to "Closed Won". Your `opp` variable will have the status value of "Closed Won" (new value) and your `oldOpp` variable will be your original (old) opportunity record which will have the status still set to "Prospecting".

Read more about [Trigger Context Variables](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm)